# Should I not speak spanish with my children and my future wife?

Tags: spanish, children, korean, dialect

I speak Spanish, because is it my mother language, and I go out with a Korean girl. It is possible that we have a friendship love. She does not speak Spanish, only English and  Korean, while I speak English well (but I am still learn English) and I speak Korean at B1 level. We speak English, because for her it is very difficult learn Spanish, and I think I am going to move to Korea the next year for her.

My  question is, should I not teach them Spanish (to her and maybe my babies).

I asked this because my family (my mother, sisters, father, etc.) do not speak English, only Spanish.

Comment: "should I do not teach their Spanish" does not make any sense. Please clarify what you're asking.

Comment: I edited mostly for language. Please check the meaning is correct and edit or revert as necessary.

Comment: Relevant question on Parenting.SE, with a very helpful answer: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/32801/25616

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should never avoid speaking your own language to your child. Especially if it's globally useful language like English or Spanish. In fact it will do your child a huge favour to be raised multilingual. Some children raised in multilingual environments get fluent a little later, but when they do they are in much better position than their monolingual peers.

Speak Spanish to your child, they will learn English and Korean at kindergarten and from TV. Don't deny them connection to your family.

Comment: the partt this: "Do not deny them connection to your family" you have reason but my famili live in other country and we are very longer, I know that my babys could learning spanish because is important in nowadays but I should like they learning japanese and standard chinese (because I learning japanese now and maybe chinese mandarin in a future I think :china and japan are country with more oportunnity of work that my country mother really

Comment: @simon it doesn't matter what country you all live in. Your child could end up moving to your home country, or could have opportunities open to them to speak Spanish. Knowing a language that is less-commonly spoken in your country is also helpful in and of itself. How many people do you think speak Spanish in Korea?

Comment: The OP uses English with her, so his children is already going to be multilingual, if I understand the question correctly (that the OP is going to SK to raise his children with her).

Comment: @RobertColumbia no I will going to speak english but I would like open a school language of spanish in korean because is it very popular in korea (spanish)